# Not able to hide or show tab bottom bar in React Native on particular screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

How can I display bottom  tabs Home | Account | BooKlist | Categories bottom tabs   visible or hide for on particular screen AddScreen in React Native. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular screen to not have the bottom tabs, it needs to be outside the tab navigator. If you have your tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator, and you place your screen at the level of the stack navigator, the bottom tabs will not be shown.

Comment: The particular screen wants to display the bottom tab bar on getting navigated by button but should not be present in Stack Navigator i.e the bottom tabs includes Home | Account | BooKlist | Categories but not that particular screen